# SEO best practices for a web feature that uses geolocation by IP Address

Tags: seo, geotargeting

I'm working on a feature that tailors content based on a geo location lookup by IP address in order to provide information based on the general area where this visitor is from.

I'm concerned that content will be interpreted as focused solely on the search engine spider's geo origin when it is indexed.

Are there SEO best practices for geo location by ip address features? I appreciate any specific tips or words of wisdom.

Answer (score 1):

You won't have any issues with search engines disliking that content as you are not offering them any information that they wouldn't be receiving if they were a regular user. You only run into issues when you serve up different content to search engines specifically for the search engine's benefit. You clearly not doing this.

Your only real issue is that search engines will only see that one specific subset of content which makes it more difficult for you to target other regions. Perhaps the ability for a user to change their region manually (i.e. a link or submitting a form). Not only does this correct incorrect geotargetting, which is not uncommon, but allows you to have URLs specific to a region. You can then submit those URLs to the search engines (most likely through an XML sitemap) and have those pages indexed as well.